# PhpStorm (Failed to collect files: Could not determine the type of file)

Tags: deployment, phpstorm

In deployment PhpStorm (7.1.2) cant upload any files with FTP.
Error says `"Failed to collect files: Could not determine the type of file"` both with gif and php file.

**idea.log:**

> 2014-08-06 08:00:38,590 [ 384809]   WARN - ins.webDeployment.TransferTask - Could not determine the type of file "ADDRESS_OF_FILE.php". org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not determine the type of file "ADDRESS_OF_FILE.php".
> Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Comment: Check your `idea.log` for details. If nothing -- enable extra logging and try again -- http://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: Added idea.log, but it says the same.

Comment: No clue (without seeing the log). Possibly http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16593 or even http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-10517. Better report to the PhpStorm's Issue Tracker with full log

Answer (score 9):

I guess it was all my fault.

After setting "Passive mode" in "Advanced options" for FTP connection all works fine.

Main Menu: Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration

"Advanced options" button

Check first checkbox "Passive mode"

Comment: There's no longer a passive mode option, I just restarted phpStorm and that worked.

Comment: This fixed it for me when I suddenly got this error in version *2017.1.3*

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error even after setting "Passive mode" in "Advanced options" for FTP connection.

Main Menu: Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration

"Advanced options" button

Check  checkbox "Instead of MLSD".

(I was also facing issue of uploading only new files which were not existing on server before. this option will fix the issue. )
Have a safe phpstorming ahead.

Answer (score 0):

my problem was very similar but it was about configuring **SFTP**. Inspired by the solutions above, I solved it as follows:

On MAC:

1. Go to Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Deployment
2. Check "Use Rsync for download, upload, sync"

If the problem still remain,

1. in the same window above, select temporarily "FTP" in "type" selector
2. Now, in the "Advanced" section, the field "Send keep alive message each" is active
3. Type "300"
4. Select again "SFTP". The field "Send keep alive message each" return unactive
5. Done